# Как создать наследование ключа в объекте от другого ключа?

Tags: javascript, объекты

Имеется объект следующего вида:

```
const main = {
    template: {
        content: document.querySelector('#template').content,
        element: document.querySelector('#template').content.querySelector('.element')
    }
}
```

У меня есть объект `main`, в котором есть объект `template`, в котором имеются два ключа `content` и `element`. Оба ключа выполняют поиск по селектору.

Вопрос, каким образом можно создать переиспользование кода и вместо полного обращения к селектору, указать переменную `content` и использовать ее в качестве основного элемента, от которого будет идти поиск?

Проще говоря, я хочу чтобы ключ `element` в объекте `template`, мог ссылаться на ключ `content` в объекте `template`, и я мог получить доступ к его результату чтобы в дальнейшем от этого отталкиваться и таким образом переиспользовать код сделав его меньше и более гибким?

Свой результат я бы примерно хотел видеть в следующем варианте:

```
const main = {
    template: {
        content: document.querySelector('#template'),
        element: main.template.content.querySelector('.element')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никак. Интерпретатор не создает объекты "построчно", чтобы во время выполнения получить доступ к предыдущей строчке объекта.

Даже если просто написать:

```js
const main = {
  element: main,
};
```

Уже получится `ReferenceError: Cannot access 'main' before initialization`. Объект должен быть полностью создан, присвоен константе, и только потом `main` вообще будет существовать ниже в коде.

Можно лишь сделать [функцию-конструктор](https://learn.javascript.ru/constructor-new) (или [класс](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)), чтобы выполнить примерно то, что вы хотели:

```
const main = {
  template: new Template('#template');
};

function Tamplate(selector) {
  this.content = document.querySelector(selector);
  this.element = this.content.querySelector('.element');
}
```

С некоторыми особенностями, выполняется как обычная функция: Свободно можно получить доступ к значениям предыдущих выражений. `this` — ссылка на создаваемый объект.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант можно попробовать использовать `геттеры`, они имеют контекст `this`.

```js
const main = {
    template: {
        content: document.querySelector('#template'),
        get title() {
            return this.content.querySelector('.title');
        },
        get subTitle() {
            return this.content.querySelector('.sub__title');
        }
    }
}

main.template.subTitle.innerText = 'My updated subtitle';

console.log(main);
```

```html
<div id="template">
    <h1 class="title">My Title</h1>
    <h4 class="sub__title">My subtitle</h4>
</div>
```